# Extract custom numbers from PHP string

Tags: php, regex, string, floating-point

I wish to extract:

`8.4` from a PHP string `ASD - 8.4 - iOS - P-CT` and

`8.3.1` from `ASD - 8.3.1 - Android - P-QL`.

Tried using `floatval($var)` but it does not work all the times - for example, if I want to use it for both of my use cases. Are there any other ways to fetch such custom numbers from the PHP string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regex to select target digit from string. Run your regex by php [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

```
$str = "ASD - 8.4 - iOS - P-CT";
preg_match("/[\d.]+/", $str, $matches);
echo $matches[0];
```

Check code result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/b3C5u)

Comment: Note this will fail if the first chunk contains a digit or a dot.

Comment: Use `/[\d.]{2,10}/` instead.

Comment: What if the first chunk contains two digits? :)

Comment: As far as my purpose goes, this answer works well. But I agree there are edge cases as you guys have mentioned above. Good learning..

Answer (score 3):

[explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) is probably your best bet here. Set your delimiter to `-` and you'll get back an array of the four parts:

```
$str = 'ASD - 8.4 - iOS - P-CT';
$parts = explode(' - ', $str);
print_r($parts);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ASD
    [1] => 8.4
    [2] => iOS
    [3] => P-CT
)
```

Comment: If the string is predictable I would use this approach.